# How to flatten PoJo and apply field values to the parent in Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Here's my PoJo structure

```
public class Company{
    String name;
    String city;
    String country;
    List<Address> previousLocations;
}

public class Address {
    String city;
    String country;

    Address(String city, String country){

       this.city =city;
       this.country = country;

}

public static void main (String[] args){
    Address a1 = new Address (“Toronto”, “Canada”);

    Address a2 = new Address (“Oakland”, “USA”);

    Company c = new Company();

    c.name = “AB TECH”;

    c.previousLocations.add(a1);

    c.previousLocations.add(a2);

   List<Company> flattened = flattenAddresses(c);

}

public List<Company> flattenAddresses(Company c){
// todo : return a list of type company
}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

Returns two objects of type Company with Toronto, Canada and Oackland, USA applied to the parent fields city and country.

Tried researching about flatmap but couldn't connect the two problems.

Comment: Honestly your question is not exactly very clear to me. You have 1 company with 2 addresses, if you want to flatten it based on the addresses, in the function flattenAddresses iterate on the addresses of the Company instance you receive and create a Company for each address. You add each instance to a new list of Company and you return the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method that assigne address to company :

```
 public static List<Company> flattenAddresses(Company c) {
    List<Company> flattened = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Address address : c.previousLocations) {
        Company newCompany = new Company();
        newCompany.name = c.name;
        newCompany.city = address.city;
        newCompany.country = address.country;
        flattened.add(newCompany);
    }
    return flattened;
}
```

and then call it in main :

```
        List<Company> flattened = flattenAddresses(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

example implementation:

```
public List<Company> flattenAddresses(Company c) {
  return c.previousLocations.stream()
    .map(address -> new Company(c.name, a.city, a.country))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

explanation:
You just have to go through the whole address list, and create new Company object for each address - using fields from each address and company name from the company object.

---

BTW. I would strongly recommend changing fields visibility to private and add getters/setters/constructors